# Optimising function parameters

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, error-handling, parameters

I am new to coding and am currently trying to fit a function to my data and find the optimized parameters which i have called 'a' and 'c' in my code which i'll show below. When i run what code i have i get the error - 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'optimization'- and i can't see how to get past this (probably due to my lack of coding knowledge tbh) Was wondering if anyone can help me improve the code so that i get values for 'a' and 'c' that will fit best to my data which is plotted.

Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy
import scipy.optimize as optimization 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

xdata=numpy.array([4.78,5.48,5.88,6.17,6.39,6.57,6.73,6.86,6.98,7.09,7.16,7.27,7.35,7.42,7.49,7.56,7.62,7.67,7.73,7.78,7.83,7.87,7.92,7.96,8.00,8.04,8.08,8.11,8.15,8.18])#x data
ydata=numpy.array([1.666,1.669,1.669,1.672,1.680,1.682,1.687,1.692,1.696,1.704,1.709,1.714,1.716,1.727,1.733,1.740,1.749,1.752,1.761,1.771,1.783,1.793,1.797,1.812,1.818,1.828,1.833,1.836,1.844,1.852])#y data 

x0 = numpy.array([0.0, 0.0]) #not sure how to treat this line??

sigma = numpy.array([1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) # errors (being omitted at the moment)

def func(x, a, c):
    return a+c*x   #definition of function 

plt.plot(xdata,ydata,label='data')
plt.show()

print.optimization.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, x0, sigma)
```

Comment: The last line should be `print(optimization.curve_fit ... )`, not `print.optimization.curve_fit ...`.

Comment: You might also want to print out before showing the plot, e.g. swapping the last two lines of code. `plt.show()` is a blocking instruction, at least in terminal.

Comment: Thanks! Both of those comments have removed the error i was getting which is good! Is there a way that i could now plot the function with the optimised parameters so that it overlays my data plot? Sorry if this seems like an easy question, just trying to get a base understanding of how to code all this

Comment: ￼Also when i run the code now, i get this line of code as the output: (array([ 1.29772981,  0.06167754]), array([[  2.43975664e-03,  -3.31181003e-04],
       [ -3.31181003e-04,   4.55502937e-05]]))

￼I was expecting more to get a value for 'a' and 'c' out of this rather than a series of array values, but think im missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
print(optimization.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, x0, sigma))
```

instead of

```
print.optimization.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, x0, sigma)
```

Comment: Thanks! That has removed the error i was getting which is good! Is there a way that i could now plot the function with the optimised parameters so that it overlays my data plot? Sorry if this seems like an easy question, just trying to get a base understanding of how to code all this

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that as I've never worked with scipy and matplotlib before